# Build a logistic regression model based on the result from another model

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I have a logistic regression model A. I want to build a new model, B, that is based on model A, but with one or more new features. This features are of a diffrent kind and needs to be trained on a dataset with another time horizon, monthly instead of annual.

In order to do this, is it posible to use the probabilities that model A has returned as input features in model B? Does that make sense?
Hope the question is clear enough. This idea is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Is the dataset to which you wish to fit Model B independent of the data-set to which you fitted Model A, or somehow derived from it, or a different view of the same raw data?

Comment: The probabilities from model A (heat model A returens) is used in model B, so in that sense they are not independent. 

I might need to re-frase my question.

Comment: its not really a valid approach because the whole idea of using a model is to combine multiple features taking account of their correlations. if you pass a probability in you are preventing your model B from accounting for the correlations of its features with the features of model A.

Comment: Yes, that is a weakness. Thanks. 
But isent that what you sort of so in  some ensemble learning metods?

Answer (score 2):

yeah, it sometimes work. I guess you want to use annual forecasting to be used as an input to the more precise month forecasting. It is a good idea, extracting information from low frequency data and use them in a higher frequency data.  But pay attention to the data splitting, since if you use the next year's data to get the model's parameter and use it to predict the months in the next year, causing data leaking. So you may only use the years before to get and use it on the next year.